# Developing on both 32 bit and 64 bit processors, how should I structure my project to automatically reference the right dlls?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll, 32bit-64bit, virtualization

I am currently in a situation where I have both 32 bit and 64 bit developer machines working on my c# project.  I have to reference a couple dlls that have both a 32 bit and a 64 bit version.  Obviously, the 32 bit machines need to reference the 32 bit dll, and the 64 bit machines the 64 bit dll.  The issue I am having is that every time a developer checks in some code, they also check in their dll references, so when someone on the other side pulls their code, it doesn't build, and they have to manually update their references back to what they should be.  Then they check in, and the other developers have to manually fix their references, etc. etc. ad nauseum.

I don't imagine this is a new problem, but it is the first time I have run into it.  Is there a common practice to have a project automatically reference the correct dll for the CPU?  Or perhaps a way to have a 32 bit and 64 bit project, each with the correct references, and a way (possibly a command line tool or some outside that can be tied into a build) to tie them together so that when new items are added or removed to one, the other will also be updated?

The other option is to have every developer use the same virtualized development environment.  If I go this route, can I virtualize a 64 bit system on 32 bit hardware, or do I have to go the other way, and virtualize 32 bit.  This will be a SaaS product, so I only have to deploy for one processor, and I would prefer that to be 64 bit.

Comment: Sounds like you need different project files for the different targets

Comment: @David Heffernan I think so too, but then my new issue is how to I keep my developers from having to manually update their project's code items when they pull from source control?

Comment: @Matthew Vines how about a different tack, why do the DLLs that are referenced need to have different names? If you are 100% managed can't you make everything target AnyCPU?

Comment: @Matthew Vines: if you are targeting only a 64bit environment, give all of your developers 64 bit hardware & OS. Will save you a lot of headaches.

Comment: @Doc Brown Couldn't you just fire up the flux capacitor, give it 1.21GW and go back in time to remove all vestiges of 32 bit computing?

Comment: @David Heffernan Unfotunately different named dlls are not the issue, we are not 100% managed, most all of our issues tie to our testing project, which uses an in memory SQLite database that uses unmanaged code.

Comment: @Doc Brown  I agree 100% that this is the way to go....eventually.  Unfotunately, we are brand new and 100% boot strapped, we have to use the hardware we have on hand until we get some money coming in.

Comment: "It doesn't build", what does that mean?  Document the error and what reference gets updated.  Assembly references have no bit-ness dependency by design, the metadata is the same.  You should only ever have a runtime problem which is easy to solve.

Comment: @Hans Passant You are correct, it is a run time error. I mis-spoke (mis-typed?). As a specific example System.Data.SqLite.dll.  This dll comes in both 32 bit and 64 bit versions, they are not interchangable.  Using the 64 bit dll on a 32 machine will cause run time exceptions, the same is true in the inverse. The exceptions thrown are fairly diverse I believe this is because the dll is largely a managed wrapper for unmanaged code.  I may be incorrect in this regard.  I am currently not on a development machine, but if it is useful I will post some of the exceptions that come up in the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you find an example for how to change the assembly reference according to your target platform:

http://www.ryangerard.net/post/8768828095/how-to-change-visual-studio-assembly-references

(You have to change the .csproj files manually). And not to forget, on the 32 bit machines choose 'x86' as target platform, while on the 64 bit machines, choose 'x64').

Comment: Thanks for the link.  This is exactly the issue I am having, and exactly what I am looking for.  I'll be giving this a shot on Monday and let you know how it works for us.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar issue but my solution is a bit different. I simply have all the developers develop with the x86 DLLs.

So, the code is actually identical on all machines. Then, at run time (and for testing), I use a launcher app which will test the OS and move around the DLLs so that at runtime the proper DLLs are used. The logic in the launcher is quite simple. Something like:

```
If IntPtr.Size = 8 Then
  '-- Copy x64 DLLs into position
Else
  '-- Copy x86 DLLs into position
End If
```

Of course, when copying, you need to copy back so you can always switch between x64 and x86 (in the case of a portable application). However, if you're installing a non-portable application then there is no need for the launcher as this OS check can all be done inside the installer (so only the proper DLLs get installed).

You will need to edit your project file to use a non-specific version of the DLLs in question (otherwise this moving around logic will not do what you want it to).

Answer (score 1):

I am going through a similar task. My solution was to use pre-buld events and specific resource folders. My 32bit reference dlls went into one folder, and the 64bit in another.

del "$(ProjectDir)\dlls*.dll" - delete all dlls from the common resource folder

xcopy "$(ProjectDir)\CommonResources" "$(ProjectDir)\dlls"/s /i /y - Copy common dlls into the resource folder

The following two commands copy the correct 32 or 64bit dlls into the resource folder

if  $(PlatformName) == x64 (xcopy "$(ProjectDir)\dlls-64\My64Bit.dll" $(ProjectDir)\dlls/s /i /y)

if  $(PlatformName) == x86 (xcopy "$(ProjectDir)\dlls-32\My32Bit.dll" $(ProjectDir)\dlls/s /i /y)

Using similar commands for the post build, I the required references to the output directory for packaging.